# C++, Writing vector<char> to ofstream skips whitespace

Tags: c++, stl, ofstream

Despite my sincerest efforts, I cannot seem to locate the bug here. I am writing a vector to an ofstream. The vector contains binary data. However, for some reason, when a whitespace character (0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x20) is supposed to be written, it is skipped.

I have tried using iterators, and a direct ofstream::write().

Here is the code I'm using. I've commented out some of the other methods I've tried.

```
void
write_file(const std::string& file,
           std::vector<uint8_t>& v)
{
  std::ofstream out(file, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

  if (!out.is_open())
    throw file_error(file, "unable to open");

  out.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

  /* ostreambuf_iterator ...
  std::ostreambuf_iterator<char> out_i(out);
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), out_i);
  */

  /* ostream_iterator ...
  std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(out, ""));
  */

  out.write((const char*) &v[0], v.size());
}
```

EDIT: And the code to read it back.

```
void
read_file(const std::string& file,
          std::vector<uint8_t>& v)
{
  std::ifstream in(file);
  v.clear();

  if (!in.is_open())
    throw file_error(file, "unable to open");

  in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

  std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(in), std::istream_iterator<char>(),
      std::back_inserter(v));
}
```

Here is an example input:

```
30 0 0 0 a 30 0 0 0 7a 70 30 0 0 0 32 73 30 0 0 0 2 71 30 0 0 4 d2
```

And this is the output I am getting when I read it back:

```
30 0 0 0 30 0 0 0 7a 70 30 0 0 0 32 73 30 0 0 0 2 71 30 0 0 4 d2
```

As you can see, 0x0a is being ommited, ostensibly because it's whitespace.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show the code where you read it back.

Comment: What does your read code look like? The problem may be there...

Comment: Did you check that the contents of the vector are in fact what you expect before write? (E.g. the input step could be removing the whitespace...)

Comment: Can you show us a hex dump of the file? Not with your program, please, but with a hex editor or `hexdump`.

Comment: Have you tried using `write` instead of streaming? `out.write(&v[0], v.size())`

Comment: For writing the file, the streambuf_iterator should do. but watch it with the char/uint8_t conversion. usually a char is 8 bits, but that isn't a guarantee. you're just guaranteed that sizeof(char)==1.

Comment: Just to reinforce (and make more explicit) @BenjaminLindley's point: this code looks fine. Chances are *very* good that the white space *is* being written to the file, and you're losing it when you try to read the data back in.

Comment: did you try removing `in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);`

Also, if you are `cat`'ing file in the bash then it wont display the space character. if you can `hexdump` your file you should be able to see the characters written in it.

Comment: I have confirmed with a hexdump the output of the program. I have, however, decided to go with boost::serialization since I will be serializing more than one vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than muck around with writing vector<>s directly, `boost::serialization` is a more effective way, using `boost::archive::binary_oarchive`.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to open the file in binary mode in the read_file function.

Answer (score 1):

The istream_iterator by design skips whitespace. Try replacing your std::copy with this:

```
std::copy(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    std::back_inserter(v));
```

The istreambuf_iterator goes directly to the streambuf object, which will avoid the whitespace processing you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I think 'a' is treated as new line.  I still have to think how to get around this.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking.